# Windows Authentication with sage pay

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, opayo

I am using Sagepay InFrame Server integration. and I am using windows authentication and when I am calling the Sagepay from my portal page (on click of the payment button),I am getting below error. and When I tried with the Forms Authentication, it is working fine.
Could you please help me to sort out this issue?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your error has not been posted. Also please consider posting it in text form rather than as an image.

Comment: I am getting Server error 5006. Unable to redirect to Vendor's website.The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because Sage Pay cannot reach your NotificationURL. You should make sure that your NotificationURL is externally visible on the internet, without authentication.